# Abstract Classes and Reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection, abstract-class

I have an abstract class which is mostly instantiated as anonymous inner classes, with abstract method implemented there. These instances get passed around, and so at a different place in the code I would like to get a copy of one of these instances, a new instance but with the method implemented the same way. Here is an example of my code:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
String id;
Entity owner;
public AbstractClass(String id){
    this.id=id;
} 
public Mover(){
    id="This is an id";
}
abstract void update();
}
```

I instantiate it like this:

```
AbstractClass instance= new AbstractClass("This is a test"){
void update(){
//do stuff
}
}
```

Later, I want a copy, not a reference, of that instance, where update() does the same stuff, but owner will be a different entity. I've tried to use reflection, (.getClass.newInstance()), but I get a java.lang.InstantiationException. Why doesn't this work and is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: I would separate these classes that modify an entity from the entity itself. That is, update method gets an Entity as parameter, instead of having it as a class field.

Comment: @Luciano: That's a great idea, and what I'll probably end up doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't instantiate anonymous inner classes through newInstance(). Non-static inner classes hold a reference to their container Object, you need that Object to create them.

See [Java Tutorial -> Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 2):

That exception is thrown in two cases (from [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InstantiationException.html)):

- the class object represents an abstract class, an interface, an array class, a primitive type, or void
- the class has no nullary constructor

Based on [a simple test I did](http://ideone.com/gymTw), in your case, the problem is that the resulting anonymous class doesn't have a nullary constructor.

Test code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            {
            Test thing = new Test(){ public void update(){ id="updated"; } };

            thing.update();

            Test thang = thing.getClass().newInstance();

            System.out.println( thing.id+" "+thang.id );
            }

            {
            Test2 thing = new Test2("name"){ public void update(){ id="updated"; } };

            thing.update();

            Test2 thang = thing.getClass().newInstance();

            System.out.println( thing.id+" "+thang.id );
            }

        }
}

abstract class Test{
    public String id;
    Test(){ id = "Empty"; }
    abstract public void update();
}

abstract class Test2{
    public String id;
    Test2(String me){ id = me; }
    abstract public void update();
}
```

The first test (with `Test`) runs just fine, the second (with `Test2`) fails on the `newInstance` call with that exception.

Comment: If I give the superclass a nullary constructor, I still get the error.

Comment: @TheTedinator It looks like it worked in my case because I was creating the anonymous class in a static method. Sean's answer explains why you get an error in a non-static context.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to clone the object, implement the interface Cloneable and add in a clone method to define what you need to do to clone said object.  In this simple case it would just mean instantiating a new object and setting the id, but I assume your actual implementation is a little more advanced.

Comment: Yes, but "what I need to do to clone said object" is what I don't know, since you can't construct an instance  of an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous inner classes require NO NAME! You shouldn't create an object with the name *'instance'*
Whenever you need a copy of your abstract class, for example, as an argument for a method, go ahead and use it directly instead of creating and using *'instance'*:

```
someObject.methodToBeUsed(new AbstractClass("This is a test"){
   void update(){
   //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's what I'm doing, the "instance" object was an example